# is there an intel C compiler flag to make long int of 64 bit under windows/cygwin?

Tags: c++, intel, long-integer, icc

I am compiling a C++ code for decoding weather forcasting products (source code here: ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib/wgrib.c) on windows under cygwin by using gcc. The program is able to handle files of any size. However, whenever I compile it with icc  (intel C compiler) I can read only file up to 2GB. I really would like to use the intel compiler cause it makes the code 2-3 time faster of either gcc -O2 or -O3 flags. I contacted developers and they said the problem relies in how icc handles long int, being 64 bit when compiled under linux with any compiler (code can handle any file size) and 32 bit when using intel compiler under windows/cygwin. Gcc under windows/cygwin would give 64 bit to long int. Any way to force intel compiler to consider all long int as 64 bit?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The library devs should have used `int64_t`; then their code would work on every platform with every compiler.

Comment: If all else fails you can try to replace every occurence of `long` (as a separate word) with `long long` and then manually fix any errors.

Comment: Btw, even if that was possible, it would break ABI, so it would probably be *very* difficult to get that to work. You would have to recompile *every* library that gets used somewhere, including the C++ and the C standard libraries.

Comment: That looks like C code, not C++. Also as @BaummitAugen said, it's really the library developers fault for not using fixed width integer types, instead relying on compiler specific data type sizes.

Comment: If GCC makes `long` 64-bit under Windows, then that is a serious bug in GCC. The Windows ABI specifically requires that `long` be a 32-bit type, same as `int`. ICC therefore does this because it conforms to the platform ABI, thus ensuring that all libraries work as expected. I'm pretty sure you are *wrong* about how GCC works; if it made `long` a 64-bit type, calling any Windows API functions would be a very tedious and error-prone process.

Comment: @CodyGray - *Cygwin* GCC puts a big fat one on Windows ABI, after all Cygwin is everything Windows isn't. Mingw GCC on the other hand does follow the Windows ABI because it is meant to compile Windows subsystem programs.

Comment: I am sure, I just retried, I compile with gcc under cygwin, i create an executable from that wgrib.c file I linked to you, I put cygwin.dll (64 bit) in the same directory where i have wgrib.exe and it reads 12 GB files with no problem. Instead if I compile wgrib.c with intel C compiler (command icl) under cygwin then wgrib.exe (with cygwin.dll in the same folder) can only read files smaller than 2 GB.

Comment: I like how the library's devs blame _Intel_ for _Microsoft_ choosing to use the LLP64 model for 64-bit Windows, and don't seem to understand that Windows isn't just a really weird version of Linux.

Comment: Why is GCC  working then?